# How to play video on Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, apple-watch

These are codes I already have:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Dou", ofType: "mp4")

var body: some View {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let player = AVPlayer.init(url: url)
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
}
}
```

It’s works great on iOS,but not working on WatchOS

And I received this WARNING:

```
Cannot find 'AVPlayer' in scope
```

Answer (score 1):

**This code is built with SwiftUI.**

First,
import SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI
```

And DO NOT FORGET AVFoundation

```
import AVFoundation
```

These are all codes:

Run it before add a video file named with “Dou.mp4” in your project.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Dou", ofType: "mp4")


var body: some View {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let 播放器 = AVPlayer.init(url: url)
 

    VStack {
       
        VideoPlayer(player: 播放器)
            
        Button(action: {播放器.isMuted.toggle()}) {
            Text("按钮")
        }
        }
    

}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```